# How can I find which peripheral a write callback was triggered by?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, callback, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-chrome-app

I'm making a Chrome app that involves connecting to several BLE peripherals and sending write messages simultaneously to them. I need to know when each write operation has finished on which peripheral so I can initiate more operations for that peripheral, but there doesn't seem to be a way to reference the peripheral from the callback function. The callback function is passed as a parameter to the Bluetooth API write function:

```
chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.writeCharacteristicValue(string characteristicId, ArrayBuffer value, function callback)
```

[The API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetoothLowEnergy#method-readCharacteristicValue) shows that the READ callback function has a characteristic parameter:

```
function(Characteristic result) {...};
```

And I've then been using `result.service.deviceAddress` to find which device the callback is for. But the WRITE callback does not have parameters.

This gives me no way to reference the peripheral that was written to, so I can't figure out which peripheral caused this write callback to run. I can see you could do this by having a unique callback function for each of a fixed number of devices, but could someone elaborate on how to do this more dynamically using a single callback function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a shared function for the callbacks (`d` is a `Device` instance):

```
var writeCallback = function (d) {
  //...
}
```

Then, in my object that keeps track of the device, I added a property for a call to this function using `this`:

```
class Device {
  constructor(device) {
    //...
    this.writeCallbackLink = (function () {
      writeCallback(this);
    }).bind(this);
  }
}
```

The `bind(this)` is vital to make sure that `this` refers to the actual object and not the runtime context. Then, when I call the API function, I use the callback link:

```
chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.writeCharacteristicValue(d.write.instanceId,
  data_buffer, d.writeCallbackLink);
```

This causes `writeCallback` to run with the `d` that triggered it as a parameter.